# How to get the train_scores to plot a learning curve without using the learning_curve fuction fo scikitlearn?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset of 21 subjects with different number of samples each one.
I made a curve (check the figure). I remove: [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30,32,34,36,38,40] samples from each subject. I am using StratifiedShuffleSplit with a 90% train_size and 10% test_size. This means:

- when I remove 10 samples, 9 will be used for training and 1 for testing
- when I remove 20 samples, 18 will be used for training and 2 for testing
- when I remove 30 samples, 27 will be used for training and 3 for testing
- when I remove 40 samples, 36 will be used for training and 4 for testing

This curve shows the accuracy(test_score) but NOT the train_score.

How can I plot the train_score without using the learning_curve function of scikit-learn? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html

The code:

```
    result_list = [] 

    #LOADING .mat FILE
    x=sio.loadmat('/home/curve.mat')['x'] 
    s_y=sio.loadmat('/home/rocio/curve.mat')['y']
    y=np.ravel(s_y)


    #SENDING THE FILE TO PANDAS
    df = pd.DataFrame(x)
    df['label']=y


    #SPECIFYING THE # OF SAMPLES TO BE REMOVED 
    for j in [10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30,32,34,36,38,40]:
        df1 = pd.concat(g.sample(j) for idx, g in df.groupby('label'))

        #TURNING THE DATAFRAME TO ARRAY
        X = df1[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]].values
        y = df1.label.values


        #Cross-validation
        clf = make_pipeline(preprocessing.RobustScaler(), neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier())   
        ####################10x2 SSS####################
        print("Cross-validation:10x10")
        xSSSmean10 = []
        for i in range(10):
            sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(2, test_size=0.1, random_state=i)

            scoresSSS = model_selection.cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=sss.split(X, y)) 
            xSSSmean10.append(scoresSSS.mean())


        result_list.append(xSSSmean10)
        print("")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StratifiedShuffleSplit.split` returns two values: train and test. You can assign the value resulting from `sss.split(X, y)` to a tuple, say `testtuple`. Then you create a new tuple which is made only of train sets, `traintuple`, constructed as follows:

```
traintuple = (testtuple[0],testtuple[0])
```

then you calculate the accuracy on just the training set:

```
scoreSSS_train = model_selection.cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=traintuple)
```

In this way both training and testing are performed on the same set.

Append the mean of `scoreSSS_train` to a new empty list just like you do with `xSSSmean10` and it should work (I could not test it, sorry).